# Could not resolve state from 'home'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a Mean-Js project in which I have to get redirected to another page in AngularJS. I used `$state.go()` to navigate . But i am getting the error as:

> Could not resolve state 'registerPage' from 'home' state .

My config file is :

```
'use strict';
```

//Setting up route

```
angular.module('SampleApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('registerPage',{
          url:'/register',
          templateUrl:'modules/Sample/Client/Views/register.html',
          data: {roles:['admin']},
          controller:'TestControl'
        });
    }
]);
```

In my controller :

```
$scope.registerPage = function(){
    $state.go('registerPage' , {});
};
```

The `registerPage` function is called in ng-click.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Does `SampleApp` is the only module in your app?

Comment: No there are other modules present in the meanjs project like Articles,Core,Chat . I have created a separate module called SampleApp

Comment: I think `SampleApp is not included in the main `module` as a dependency.

Comment: Exactly as @Sravan say. Try including it in tthe main module (`angular.module('myMainModule', ['SampleApp', .....])`)

Answer (score 2):

**Your custom module:**

```
angular.module('SampleApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('registerPage',{
          url:'/register',
          templateUrl:'modules/Sample/Client/Views/register.html',
          data: {roles:['admin']},
          controller:'TestControl'
        });

      }
      ]);
```

**Your main module, Include `sampleApp`, and other dependencies**

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['SampleApp', 'otherDependencies'])
```